# How can I optimise or simplify my extremely slow SQL query/function/procedure?

Tags: sql-server

**Simplified system overview**

An Account has a unique AccountID and an OpeningBalance amount (this is a static amount which can be understood to reference the beginning of time BOT for the Account); there are Transactions which have a CreditAmount, DebitAmount, DateStamp and a reference to an Account by FK_AccountID.

**The requirements**

For a given Account, what is the OpeningBalance for a given date period Date1 to Date2? Naturally, if Date1 = BOT then we have the answer already. However, as the OpeningBalance for any given date period is equal to the ClosingBalance for the previous date period, in order to calculate for this period we need to first calculate the previous period's ClosingBalance, and then we have our answer.

**The solution/issue(s)**

I have written a solution (T-SQL, SQL Server 2008) with a couple of functions for the logic which does work, but calculating OpeningBalance for ALL Accounts (100+) in one go utilises a WHILE loop over every Account which is NOT usable/scalable, taking in the order of approximately 1 second per Account.

**Question**

Is there way to solve this problem without a [slow] loop?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved my problem soon after by refactoring to use many nested CASE statements in my main SELECT query instead of my initial solution of joining on a call to the function which looped over every Account row to return a table. It's not ideal as of course I had to pull in most of the function logic (into the CASE structure which SQL Server handles itself, so no horrid looping) but it's very quick now, though lacks the clarity of the original function.